# What are the benefits of a embeded web server over war deployment?(If any)

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jetty, netty

Jetty,Tomcat 7 ,Netty provided an embedded mode where it can run inside the as a part of the java application.
What are the benefits/use-cases of this over deploying a war on older versions of tomcat?

Except not having to explicitly start a web server during development

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Comment: Answers for this are going to be mostly opinion based.